# USB port not working because of short circuit

Tags: usb

My USB port is not working because I am a <strike>genius</strike> and shorted the wires.
I got an over voltage warning and stopped.
I haven't tried anything yet.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the USB port on the front or back of the computer?  If it is on the back, it is likely part of the motherboard and nothing you can do.  If it is on the front you could unplug the cable from the motherboard, and at least it won't short any more.  The actual port however, is permanently dead.  You would need to find unsolder, and replace the chip you zapped, and that is beyond most normal mortals skill sets.

Comment: The best way to fix it is to buy a new motherboard.  As long as your getting a new one you might as well get an upgraded one that match your CPU and memory.  If you can't replace it your self you will have to find a local computer store to do it for you.

Comment: Overvoltage warning? Did you mean "overcurrent"?

Comment: @AliChen: Since the D+ and D- wires are supposed to swing between 0V and 3.3V, shorting either of them to VBUS (5V or slightly more) would indeed be "overvoltage".

Comment: @BenVoigt, USB PHY has no means to detect if D+ or D- are above 3.3V. So there could be no possibility for any system to issue "overvoltage" warning.

Comment: @AliChen: I believe you mean that the standard register interface has no flag bit to report it.  It's entirely possible to build a PHY circuit that includes the necessary comparators, and entirely possible to report that to software via extended registers that aren't part of the xHCI standards.  And certainly USB test equipment does detect and report such things, so your claim that "there could be no possibility for any system to issue overvoltage warning" is ludicrous.  I do agree though that most commodity USB controllers won't do so.

Comment: @BenVoigt, of course, everything is possible, in theory. I am just telling you that in reality no USB 2.0 PHY ever made on the market has any comparator to detect 3.3 V overvoltage. And no standard interface between PHY and USB controller (UTMI or ULPI) has defined such status. That's why no host controller interface has any flag to report this condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you don't need to do anything. USB ports must be protected from overcurrent by specifications, so a USB compliant device should recover electrically.

However, your USB controller might require "user intervention" to get the port functionality back. Either your system should give an option to "reset port" or controller, or you disable and re-enable the entire USB root, or simply reboot the computer.

Comment: This protects the VBUS regulator.  It won't save the circuitry on D+ and D- if shorted to VBUS.

Comment: @BenVoigt According to original USB 2.0 specifications, D+ and D- must be tolerant to  +5V overvoltage.  " This requirement must be met for max value of VBUS (5.25 V). A USB transceiver is recommended, but not required, to withstand a continuous short of D+ and/or D- to VBUS for a minimum of 24 hours without degradation. " Later the requirement was relaxed to shorting with 15 Ohm resistor, and later it was completely abandoned. So, it depends on when the USB controller was made.

Answer (score 2):

Is it just one USB port that is not working or are all of your USB ports not working?

USB ports are usually protected from over currents by fuses (sometimes a single fuse will be responsible for protecting 2 USB ports). These fuses work by generating heat. When the fuse gets too hot, the fuse opens up and stops all power going to the USB port. When the fuse cools down, it closes and allows power to go back to the port.

When you short circuited the USB port, you likely destroyed the fuse completely. However, if all of your USB ports are not working then the USB controller is likely dead. But either way, your USB port(s) are not fixable as both components are part of the motherboard.

Comment: It's just one USB port.

Comment: Then I'd be looking at a failed fuse. However, why it failed is beyond my knowledge. These fuses exists for this exact reason and should normally be able to survive such events. It happened to me when a USB cable shorted internally and still, the USB port involved works. I guess you were just unlucky.

Comment: This fuse protects the VBUS regulator.  It won't save the circuitry on D+ and D- if shorted to VBUS.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's a fried USB controller, and since it's most likely soldered to the motherboard, you can't do much (if anything at all). If it's a desktop machine, you can buy a PCIe USB controller.